# Can CLion move an in-the-class method definition out-of-class?

Tags: c++, clion, member-functions

Common background goes first. In C++, you can write a method definition right inside the class body, as illustrated in the following Effective-C++ styled `Widget` class:

```
class Widget {
  unsigned TheSize;
public:
  unsigned getSize() const { return TheSize; }
};
```

I know this fashion is also called *in-the-class definition* and it is `inline` implicitly (without telling the compiler with keyword). On the other hand, you can write the method out of the class, explicitly qualifying its name, like:

```
class Widget {
  unsigned TheSize;
public:
  unsigned getSize() const;
};

unsigned Widget::getSize() const {
  return TheSize;
}
```

Now comes the question. I want to transform some classes written in the *in-the-class* fashion to the *out-of-class* fashion, using [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/), the new IDE made by JetBrains for C/C++. I wonder whether this nice-looking IDE provides builtin support for this refactoring. I can't see it has a refactoring called **Pull Inline Method Out of Class** though it does have the opposite [Inline Method](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/inline-method.html) refactoring tool.

**Edit:** The CLion version I am using:

```
CLion 2018.3.1
Build #CL-183.4588.63, built on December 4, 2018
Licensed to CLion Evaluator
Expiration date: January 10, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-42-generic
```

Comment: Hi @cgsdfc. Now sure about the whole class, but if you put the cursor on some class method and press `alt+enter` you can call `Split function into declaration and definition` action

Comment: @MaximBanaev Nice shot! That's exactly what I am looking for! It works pretty well.

Comment: Very nice @MaximBanaev! You should make this an answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is as @MaximBanaev said in the comments. I found no way to move all definitions into a .cpp file. So, what I did was, I created a `New -> C/C++ Source File` (with the same name as the .hpp file, but it's not mandatory) with `Add to target` ticked. Then I included the header file in the source file. After that, when I put the cursor on the method name, hit `Alt + Enter`, and selected `Split function into declaration and definition`, it left only the declaration in the header file, and automatically moved the definition into the source file.

(Oh and, this doesn't work for templated classes.)